# Accidentally created a duplicate branch with different capitalization (Master), how to move it backto master?

Tags: git, branch

Whilst moving data from a subbranch back to the `master` branch, I accidentally created a `Master` branch (with a capital M).
The toolset on Windows seems to be oblivious to the difference in capitalization and in my local repo I only have two branches:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\Me\source\repos\Me\MyProject\.git\logs\refs\remotes\origin

[.]                 [..]                64ThreadsPerBlock   HEAD                master
```

However in the remote I have three branches:

```
64threadsPerBlock
Master
master
```

How do I fix things, so that the remote does not have a `Master` and it's in sync with the local `master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a Linux system, this is easy, because Git there is *always* case-sensitive: `readme` and `README` are two different *files* and `master` and `Master` are two different branches.

If you're on a typical Windows or macOS file system, with case-insensitive native file names,<sup>1</sup> it gets messy: *Git* thinks that `master` and `Master` are *two different names* but **sometimes** *uses* those names as ordinary files in the file system.  It then expects those two different names to remain different, but the OS insists on behaving otherwise.  Since Git only does this *sometimes*, though, sometimes it works the way Git thinks it should.

What you can do is make use of two facts:

1. The *other* system obviously is treating the two names as different.
2. Git doesn't actually care *what* a branch name is—how it's spelled, etc—it just cares about the stored *hash ID* in each name.

So, step 1 of fixing the problem is to run:

```
git ls-remote origin
```

This will spit out a few, or many, lines of output, e..g:

```
e2850a27a95c6f5b141dd88398b1702d2e524a81    HEAD
898f80736c75878acc02dc55672317fcc0e0a5a6    refs/heads/maint
e2850a27a95c6f5b141dd88398b1702d2e524a81    refs/heads/master
5d2a92d10f831493d4b0b258ee3cd18d4a7ae995    refs/heads/next
4141ae219919d2e29f3939983be8501770f247a3    refs/heads/seen
1637c5d31a0b0df8e3dcef7072720fe0381520ac    refs/heads/todo
d5aef6e4d58cfe1549adef5b436f3ace984e8c86    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0
3d654be48f65545c4d3e35f5d3bbed5489820930    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0^{}
[... tons of tags snipped here]
```

The thing on the left, in each column, is the raw hash ID.  **This raw hash ID is what Git cares about.**  The thing on the right is the *name under which the other Git repository is storing the raw hash ID*.  The `refs/heads/*` names are their branch names.

You may wish to save all of this output in a file.  Note, too, that we're counting on the other Git repository not to have any *changes made to it* while we're working.  If it is a highly active repository, you're better off bringing up a Linux system (or Linux VM) and just doing ordinary Git stuff in it.

(Side note: `git ls-remote -h origin` trims the output to *just* the branch names, which can be pretty handy if there are many tags.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, case-sensitivity is *per file system*.  On macOS you can easily set up a case-sensitive disk image, mount it, clone there, and fix everything there, without even having to bother with a VM.  There may be case-sensitive file systems available for Windows systems as well, but I don't know of any, nor whether there's anything as relatively easy as the macOS ".dmg" trick.

---

#### What to do after step 1

If their `master` and `Master` are both storing the *same* raw hash ID, you can now just ask them to *delete* one of the two names:

```
git push --delete origin Master
```

(assuming the one you want to get rid of is the one with the one uppercase `M`).  You are now done.

If their `master` and `Master` store *different* raw hash IDs, you must now figure out what to do about this.  You *are* going to delete one of these two names.  If their `master` is *ahead of* their `Master`, you can do the same thing you would do if they were equal: just delete their `Master`.  But if their `master` is *behind* their `Master`, or both are ahead of and behind each other, you can't quite do that, at least not safely.

Understanding this requires understanding what "ahead of" and "behind" actually *mean*.  Commit hash IDs, in Git, are part of a *directed acyclic graph* or *DAG*.  We need a brief aside about graph theory and partially ordered sets.

#### Partially ordered sets

Most people are familiar with *total order*, which we get with, e.g., integers: 1 comes before 2, 2 comes before 3.  Any number greater than 3 comes after all of these.

In a graph, however, we can have a simple line:

```
A--B--C--D--...
```

or a *fork:*

```
     C   <-- last
    /
A--B
    \
     D   <-- also-last
```

Here, A comes before B, and B comes before both C and D, but we can't say that C comes before or after D.  In a sense, they're both in the same spot, right after B.

This is also the case for Git commits.  If each uppercase letter stands in for some raw commit hash, and `last` and `also-last` are actually `master` and `Master`, then we have a case where *deleting* one of the two *names* will make it impossible for Git to find the two "last" commits.  Git actually works by having names that identify each "last commit", and working backwards from there, so Git *needs* both names to *find* both commits `C` and `D` here.

#### Applying that partial order thing to Git

In Git-practical terms, what this means is that if you can determine that `master` really "comes after" `Master`—if they have:

```
...--G--H   <-- Master
         \
          I   <-- master
```

then you can just delete `Master` safely.  They will now have:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master
```

and they will still be able to find all their commits.

But if that's *not* safe, you should have them create a new name for the *later* commit.  That is, if they have this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- Master
```

or this:

```
       H   <-- master
      /
...--G
      \
       I   <-- Master
```

then what you should do is create, in their Git repository, a *new name* that identifies the *same* commit as their `Master`.  To do this, you can run:

```
git push origin <hash>:<new-name>
```

For instance, if the hash ID for their `master` is `deadbeef`, and you choose as the new branch name, the name `save-for-now`, you would run:

```
git push origin deadbeef:save-for-now
```

This will create, in *their* Git repository, this kind of situation:

```
       H   <-- master
      /
...--G
      \
       I   <-- Master, save-for-now
```

It's now safe to run:

```
git push origin --delete Master
```

to ask them to *delete* their name `Master`:

```
       H   <-- master
      /
...--G
      \
       I   <-- save-for-now
```

Note that if you're in a "safe" situation, such as when both names identify the same last commit, you can still do this safe stuff:

```
git push origin <hash>:save-for-now
```

creates:

```
...--G--H   <-- Master, master, save-for-now
```

and then deleting `Master` gives you:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, save-for-now
```

(all in *their* Git repository of course).

#### Now that you've fixed things, just run `git fetch --prune origin`

You can now have your Git re-synchronize your repository with their Git repository.  You *may* have to run this `git fetch --prune origin` twice, because your local Git could conceivably delete the name `Master` after updating `master`, and with your Git storing that name in a file, your Git might delete both names, but this is safe because the *second* `git fetch` will restore it.  (In general Git seems to do these in ASCII order so that a single fetch will work right, but I don't know if this is guaranteed for all Git versions past and future.)

If all the commits were safe before, so that you could just safely delete their `Master`, you now have a normal setup in which to solve everything normally.  If they *weren't* safe before, you now have an `origin/safe-for-now` *remote-tracking name* in your own Git repository.  This name doesn't clash with your `origin/master` name, so there is no problem solving everything normally.

Either way, in other words, it's now safe to go back to work.