# Delete remote branch with capitalization difference

Tags: git

Recently, there was a branch called "regression" that I was supposed to be working on. I accidentally made my commits to "Regression" instead.

Because the changes are relatively small, I decided to just write down what they were and completely reset my local state, which now has neither branch.

I would like to delete the remote branch "Regression" while *not* deleting "regression" in the process.

I am very concerned if I just do "git push -d origin Regression" I'll accidentally delete "regression" as well, because my local Git seems to be very confused about which is which.

How can I ensure this does not happen and I only delete the right one?

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64629409/accidentally-created-a-duplicate-branch-with-different-capitalization-master) but it actually skips over the deleting step of the incorrect branch, so I'm not sure on that part.

I have the hash of both branches, but I could not find out how to delete a branch based on that, if it's even possible.

Comment: Where are you pushing things to, Github/Gitlab or something you're hosting yourself? And what is your local operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Branches map to files on disk, stored under the `.git` directory. If you have a case-insensitive file system (Windows, MacOS) then you cannot have two branches whose names differ only in case.

However, under Linux, the file system is case sensitive, meaning two files can exist in the same location and their names can differ only by case. This means that, for example Github, which is hosted on Linux, has no problem having branches called `xyz` and `XYZ`, and you can safely refer to a branch called `XYZ` and be certain that you're not inadvertently affecting the remote branch `xyz`.

If you are pushing some place with a case-sensitive file system, you can safely run `git push origin :Regression` and be certain that you are not affecting the `regression` branch.

Comment: So in short I need to have someone on a Linux machine do the deletion? Thank you.

Comment: No, absolutely not, involving a Linux machine now won't help. If your pushing to a Linux machine, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the commit hash you want the final branch to point to, one approach is simply to delete *both* branches:

1. Create a new branch at the relevant commit e.g. `git branch regression-backup abc123def`, where `abc123def` is the commit hash
2. Delete with `git push -d origin Regression`
3. If that deletes both branches, simply recreate the correct one with `git branch regression regression-backup`, and push it to the remote

Comment: We've been using Bitbucket and the correct "regression" branch has some history tied to it with a PR with comments and so on. I don't want to accidentally delete it if at all possible and lose that. I'll keep this in mind if it's desperate though.

Comment: @TylerShellberg I don't know BitBucket well, but I'm 90% sure deleting the branch won't delete any of that, since branches in git are designed to be somewhat disposable. But better safe than sorry, I guess.